# Would it be possible to generate muons using neutrinos and electrons?

Tags: particle-physics, standard-model, leptons

The decay products for a muon are an electron, a muon neutrino, and a electron antineutrino. As the decay products for a neutron (electron, proton, neutrino) can combine together to form a neutron again, would it be possible to generate muons using electrons and neutrinos as long as they have sufficient energy?

Comment: Yes, trivially, but with very tiny chances of happening.

Comment: It almost impossible collide two neutrinos

Comment: But you can collide one electron with one electron antineutrino and get one muon with one muon antineutrino

Comment: why would the chance of it happening be very low?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there are two possibilities for inverse muon decay: $\nu_\mu e^- \rightarrow \nu_e \mu^-$ and $\bar{\nu}_e e^- \rightarrow \bar{\nu}_\mu \mu^-$.  The first process has been observed, but not yet the second.

The standard model $\nu_\mu e^- \rightarrow \nu_e \mu^-$ [lowest-order cross-section](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevD.104.092010) for a muon neutrino - electron interaction with centre-of-mass energy squared $s$ is (for $M_W^2\gg s \gg m_\mu^2$):

$$
\sigma(\nu_\mu e^- \rightarrow \nu_e \mu^-) \approx \frac{G^2_F}{\pi} s 
$$

I believe this process was first observed by the [CHARM](https://doi.org/10.1016/0370-2693(80)90127-6) experiment at CERN and later by the [CCFR](https://doi.org/10.1016/0370-2693(90)91099-W) and other experiments at Fermilab. The subsequent [CHARM II](https://doi.org/10.1016/0370-2693(95)01298-6) experiment observed $15758 \pm 324$ $\nu_\mu e^- \rightarrow \nu_e \mu^-$ events, in agreement with the expected number.

The cross-section for $\bar{\nu}_e e^- \rightarrow \bar{\nu}_\mu \mu^-$ is [comparable](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevD.107.093005) (for $M_W^2\gg s \gg m_\mu^2$):
$$
\sigma(\bar{\nu}_e e^- \rightarrow \bar{\nu}_\mu \mu^-) \approx \frac{G^2_F}{3\pi} s 
$$
but it has not yet been observed because it is almost impossible to make a pure enough high-energy anti-electron-neutrino beam.  For electrons at rest, the minimum neutrino energy threshold for $\bar{\nu}_e e^- \rightarrow \bar{\nu}_\mu \mu^-$ is about $m_\mu^2/2E_\nu = 10.9$ GeV. Such [high energy neutrinos are produced](https://doi.org/10.48550/arXiv.1805.01373) by smashing protons into targets which produce lots of charged pions and kaons whose decays mostly produce muon neutrinos and anti-neutrinos. For example, the NuTeV "anti-neutrino" beam was $98\%$ $\bar{\nu}_\mu$ and only $1.6\%$ $\bar{\nu}_e$, and although they [observed 24 events](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-ex/0104029) consistent with $\bar{\nu} e^- \rightarrow \bar{\nu} \mu^-$, this number was consistent with backgrounds such as beam impurities and muon charge misidentification. These backgrounds were about $7$ times greater than the expected $\bar{\nu}_e e^- \rightarrow \bar{\nu}_\mu \mu^-$ signal.